# How to send a message from Server A to Server B using MSMQ?

Tags: windows, msmq, message-queue

How do I setup a message queue that automatically sends all it's messages to another server?

I'm working on a proof of concept for a system that needs to run on multiple servers, writing to local message queues, then have a central service on another server running that reads its local queue to pick up all the messages from the other servers.

From what I've read I believe this is possible, but I'm not seeing how to set it up...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your application send a message to a remote computer, the msmq service actually write the message to a local queue ( temporary outgoing queue). So practically the behaver of msmq is exactly what you want. Can you elaborate more about your scenario?

**Update to comment:** There is one problem. You can't create a remote queue.

Comment: Okay, so it's automatic? I just create the queue "ComputerName\QueueName" and then write to it, and it sends through the local queue and guarantees that it gets there?